# What do I do with extra ECTS points?

Tags: course-evaluation

I did an exchange semester and a few other extra curricular activities and ended up with a few extra credit points.

Can I do anything with them or are they basically useless?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the rules of your country/university. Basically, the uses are the following:

- When your director of studies allows, they count for mandatory or optional courses in your studies.
- They can be used to proved that you studied enough - e.g. to be allowed to stay a student or for financial benefits for which you have to be a student to receive them. Or also to justify the finanical help you received for your exchange semester.
- They can be used to prove that you studied much - you might be eligible for stipendia if you took a lot of courses (most likely, you need good grades for them too).

Other than that, you might have learned something. Whether or not this was worth the effort can only you decide.